# yii2 При сохранении формы пустые поля делать null

Tags: php, yii2, mvc

Как при сохранении в БД через модель полученных из формы данных сделать так, чтобы пустые (незаполненные и необязательные) значения вставлялись в БД не как `''`, а как `null`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать [стандартный](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-core-validators.html#default) валидатор, добавьте это правило в свою модель

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
       // ...
       ['attribute', 'default', 'value' => null],
       // ...
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Как это сделать в yii2 не знаю, можно самостоятельно формировать запрос

```
SET fieldname = NULL
```